# PHP regex get last characters until match

Tags: php, regex

So I have a string like: "Product name (#15)".
Now I want to get the ID out of the string, problem is that the ID of the product can variate in lenght, so I wont be able to just get the last characters.
Also the product name may have some special characters.

How can I get the ID with a regex, which should start looking for the number from the right?

Comment: At least post that much code that we could understand what really you want to achieve and what have you done so far?

Comment: @vard , thank you sir, that did the trick.

Comment: give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: @Andrew And give a man a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) he will regex for a lifetime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$str =  "Product name (#15)";

preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $m); // Assuming only the id part will be in digits
echo $m[0]; // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = '/.*\(\#(\d+)\)/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```